# Typescript: Apply default values to optional fields nested in an optional object

Tags: typescript

I am making a component library that has quite a few options. If the `options` object is not passed in, I need all fields of the `objects` value to be defaults. From there, I need each field of the `options` object be a default value if the field is not passed in.

Currently the best I can do is provide a default if the `options` value is not provided at all with the following code:

```
interface Foo {
    bar;
    options?: {
        option1?: string;
        option2?: string;
        option3?: string;
    };
}

function foo({ bar, options = { option1: 'foo', option2: 'bar', option3: 'baz' }) { ... }
```

This works as expected. All values are the defaults ('foo', 'bar', and 'baz'). However, I can't get this working if I add one or more fields.

Desired output/functionality:

```
foo(x);

option1 = 'foo'
option2 = 'bar'
option3 = 'baz'


foo(x, { option1: 'hello world' });

option1 = 'hello world'
option2 = 'bar'
option3 = 'baz'
```

So on and so forth.

How can I get the fields (option1, 2, & 3) to be defaults if the `options` object is provided, but the specific field is not? Do let me know if, while possible, this is discouraged. I just don't know a better way to do this as of now.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that in parameter defaults. I think the best you can do is: `options = {}` then inside the function `options = { option1: 'foo', /* all your defaults here then spread */ ...options }`

Comment: Sorry? Not sure I follow. The parameter `options` can't reference itself. You can't use `...options` inside the `options` object?

Comment: I'm doing a reassignment that involves spreading inside the function, not giving a default value. The default you'd give would be an empty object—it just needs to be spreadable

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry, totally blanked and basically read over the first part of the sentence entirely! That works great! it's also probably better as it's far more readable this way. If you want to add an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @AndrewLi, the best way to go about this was with spreading the parameters into an object containing default values, like so:

```
interface Options: {
    option1?: string;
    option2?: string;
    option3?: string;
}

function foo(props: { bar: string, options: Options }) {
    const {
        option1,
        option2,
        option3
    }: Options = { 
        option1 = 'foo',
        option2 = 'bar',
        option3 = 'baz',
        ...props.options
    };
}
```